# jquery search removes table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to make something like a search box.
There's a text box and a table as shown in the html code below:

```
<input id="sbox" type="text" class="textbox" value=""></input>
<table>
  <tr><td>lemon</td></tr>
  <tr><td>orange</td></tr>
  <tr><td>watermelon</td></tr>
  <tr><td>coconut</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can i use jQuery to look for the table row with the matching value.
for example user typed in **lemon** and the jquery will find the table row with the "lemon" value and **display:none others which don't have lemon value**

and the results will be :

```
<input id="sbox" type="text" class="textbox" value=""></input>
<table>
  <tr><td>lemon</td></tr>
  <tr style="display:none;"><td>orange</td></tr>
  <tr style="display:none;"><td>watermelon</td></tr>
  <tr style="display:none;"><td>coconut</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to activate the search so I'll pretend that you have a button with an id of "go". You could use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like this:

```
$('#go').click(function() {
    var want = $.trim($('#sbox').val());
    $('table tr > td').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) != want;
    }).parent().hide();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qWaDs/2/

You might want to add some [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) calls if you want a case-insensitive search:

```
$('#go').click(function() {
    var want = $.trim($('#sbox').val()).toLowerCase();
    $('table tr > td').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase() != want;
    }).parent().hide();
});
```

The [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) calls are necessary in case your HTML ends up as:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        lemon
    </td>
</tr>
<!--...-->
```

If you don't `$.trim` that row or cell you'll end up with unwanted whitespace in your `.text` return value. There's no good reason to bind your code's behavior too tightly to the precise format of your HTML.

Comment: can i use textbox .keydown function

Comment: @sm21guy: Yes, you could do that if you wanted to detect someone hitting the Enter key. Also, I missed a `parent()` call in my original  so I fixed that; probably wouldn't make any visual difference but you did want to hide the rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td')
    .filter(function() { return $(this).text() != 'lemon'; })
    .closest('tr')
    .hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code,

```
$("tr").hide();
$("td:contains('lemon')").parents('tr').show();
```

Comment: `contains` also makes it match 'lemonfoobar'.

Comment: The [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selects "all elements that contain the specified text", it doesn't do an exact match.